# How to stop my css declaration from being overridden

Tags: html, css

I have a div with classes of A B C
I added a style to c to show the color as "Red";
The problem is it's overridden from the styles of A and B.

I read that `!important` only prevents the css being overridden by the inline style but does not prevent the override by other css.

How do I mark the style of C as the strongest?

Comment: Add !important, as you said, it should work. Like so `color: red !important;`

Comment: Can you post the CSS for A, B and C please?

Comment: @jValdron, tried that already, didn't work

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Increase the [specificity](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) of rule C above that of rules A and B. Normally I would include some explanation here, but the one over at the linked site is *superb*.

Answer (score 1):

An **!important** declaration provides a way for a stylesheet author to give a CSS value more weight than it naturally has. It should be noted here that the phrase “!important declaration” is a reference to an entire CSS declaration, including property and value, with !important added.

Here is a simple code example that clearly illustrates how !important affects the natural way that styles are applied:

```
#example {
        font-size: 14px !important;
    }

    #container #example {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

In the above code sample, the element with the id of “example” will have text sized at 14px, due to the addition of !important.

Answer (score 0):

`!important` should work just fine, but if not you can chain your classes in your declaration like so:

`div.a.c,div.b.c,div.a.b.c
 {
 color:red
 }`

Answer (score 0):

```
div.a, div.b {
    background-color: #00f;
}
div.c {
    background-color: #f00 !important;
}
```

The `!important` will up priority of rule and inheritance will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.a, div.b, div.c {
  background-color: #00f;
} 
div.c {
   background-color: #f00;
}
```

should work, CSS is sequential. This means the last style for that element is applied of no more specific style is available. More specific would be for example

```
body div.c {
   background-color: #f00;
}
```